Save files in database and not in local folder - Filament3 - Laravel
I would like to store the images or all the files in a table in my database and not in the public folder of laravel or Filament3.
I am developing a project with filament3 of laravel. And the images are saved locally and we would like those images to be saved in the database since we are several people working in a team and we are all in different locations. The ideal would be that everything is saved in the database because in the public folder is an error because our project is uploaded to github periodically.

do not save the files in the db
